# What does this Union mean? c++

Tags: c++, unions

So I was given a Union like this:

```
union A
{
    struct{
        SomeType B;
    }b;
    struct{
        SomeType C;
    }c;
}a[2];
```

What does that a[2] mean?

Comment: The inner anon. structs look ill-formed.  Shouldn't there be semi-colons after `B` and `C`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) named `a` of size 2 of the type `A` which is a `union`.  This is the same for all class types.

It would be the same as

```
union A
{
    struct{
        SomeType B;
    }b;
    struct{
        SomeType C;
    }c;
};

A a[2];
```

Comment: notice that, from a type perspective, **there's no difference between a class and a struct**.

Comment: Could you add semicolons after the members of the structs? I submitted an edit for the same to the question already.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I fixed the wording. Is that better?

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't think it was wrong in the first place, just wanted to make sure the reader doesn't think there's a natural difference of where you can use a `struct` or a `class`

Comment: So can a[0] be b and a[1] be c? Or if a[0] is b ,a[1] should also be b?

Comment: @andyz Do you know what an array is?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes i do i m just lil confused when those two combined together

Comment: @andyz Okay.  They are two different element so `a[0]` could be using `b` and `a[1]` could be using `c` or it could be the other way around or they could both be using the same type.  Since they are independent of each other they do not affect each other.

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
union A
{
    struct{
        SomeType B
    }b;
    struct{
        SomeType C
    }c;
}a[2];
```

in fact is equivalent to the following two declarations

```
union A
{
    struct{
        SomeType B
    }b;
    struct{
        SomeType C
    }c;
};

A a[2];
```

That is `a` is an array of two elements of type `union A`.

Answer (score 0):

The `a[2]` is declaring a variable, `a`, that is an array of type `A`, that has a size of `2`.